# Detect language of sentences (20 to 200 characters).

Tags: php

**Background:**

- I would like to automatically detect the language written by the user in a field text.
- Users would write from 10 to 200 characters.
- Most are going to be Spanish and English.
- I'm programming a web with PHP and Code Igniter.

**My solution:** I'm using libraries. The best I've found is *Text LanguageDetect 0.3.0*. But it failures sometimes (even if I restrict the language set to Spanish and English).

**Help/Advice:** 
Is it because the library is not so good? Do you know anyone better?
Or is it because I asking to much? Detect language with only 20 characters.

Thanks!

Comment: probably because 20 characters might be a bad sample size. usually you want to just look for the most common words in that language would be your best bet

Comment: Can you give an example of a 20 character text that fails to be detected properly?

Comment: Hello Mr Lister. Let me clarify. With 20 character it works well if I restrict the language set to English and Spanish (then I only have problems with < 10 characters). But, if I include Portuguese or Italian it fails to detect Spanish (a lot of times with 20 ch., and sometimes with long sentences ->100 ch.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use Google Translate API, but this service non-free

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#detect-language

Comment: Thanks Victor. I was aware of this tool, but first, if possible, I'd like to try with free  ones.

Comment: For trying just go to http://translate.google.com/ , enter your text and in the dropdown menu "From" select option "Detect Language"